Why I am getting `this generic parameter must be used with a generic type parameter` error for following code?
I am not able to figure out why following code is giving me error this generic parameter must be used with a generic type parameter
use anyhow::Result;
use std::path::Path;

fn test_file(path: impl AsRef<Path>, filename: &str) -> Result<Option<impl AsRef<Path>>> {
    ...
    if path.join(filename).exist() {
        Ok(Some(path))
    } else if current_directory == path {
        Ok(None)
    } else {
        test_file(path.parent().context("{filename} not found")?, filename)
    }
}

As you can see this is a recursive function and I am getting error in else condition while passing path for parent directory, but surprisingly if I change the return type to Result<bool> with following function body then compiler passes without any error.
use anyhow::Result;
use std::path::Path;

fn test_file(path: impl AsRef<Path>, filename: &str) -> Result<bool> {
    ...
    if path.join(filename).exist() {
        Ok(true)
    } else if current_directory == path {
        Ok(false)
    } else {
        test_file(path.parent().context("{filename} not found")?, filename)
    }
}

Playground
I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Why are you returning impl AsRef<Path>? Just return PathBuf.

That's right, but I am not able to understand why compiler is complaining for impl AsRef<Path>?

If I'm being honest, I can't figure it out either. If you follow the compiler's suggestion and do test_file<T: AsRef<Path>>(path: T, it still complains (with a completely nonsensical diagnostic, I might add), but if you do test_file(path: &Path, then it works. It seems to be the combination of path being generic and return-position impl but I'll be damned if I can work out why. It smells a bit like a bug to me, but I can't say that for certain.

@cdhowie while the error seems confusing, it's quite literally describing the problem, you can't use test_file with &Path because that's not guaranteed to return the same type as when called with T, you must use the type parameter T→ "this generic parameter must be used with a generic type parameter" is quite literally what you have to do.

repro playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c763ec5ef6d524a9604b6f0953374c7

@cafce25 The wording of the error message is absolutely atrocious then.

The problem is that the returned type could depend on the type parameter1, hence the only valid test_file to recurse to has to have the same type parameters as the current one, but &Path (the result of path.parent().context("{filename} not found")?) is not necessarily the same as the type passed in.
Here is an example of that:
trait Foo {
    type A: AsRef<str>;
    fn foo(&self) -> Self::A;
}

impl Foo for () {
    type A = &'static str;
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
        "unit"
    }
}

impl Foo for String {
    type A = String;
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        String::from("string")
    }
}

fn test(x: impl Foo) -> impl AsRef<str> {
    x.foo()
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(test(String::new()).as_ref());
    dbg!(test(()).as_ref());
}


1) analyzing the body would show it's always a wrapped PathBuf but that's not something the compiler does factor in

The simple answer is to just always return PathBuf.  Conveying to the caller that they have an owned value is actually useful since that avoids an unnecessary clone should they need to turn it into an owned value.
fn test_file(path: impl AsRef<Path>, filename: &str) -> Result<Option<PathBuf>> {

(Playground)
